# Websocket blocking incoming request from server

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, wamp, netty

**Configuration**

I have a java client connected to a server using websockets. I'm using netty framework as the websocket implementation. The server sends a ping to the client and the client responds with a pong frame, failure to do so will result in the server closing the connection.

**Scenario**

My client sends multiple request to the server and expects a response in return.  Now if the response of the first request is large, then the subsequent responses and ping are blocked until the client completely downloads the first request. Since the ping is also blocked, the server assumes the connection is broken and forces a close on the socket and client has to then reconnect and again send the 2 requests since the response was not complete last time.

**Question**

Is there a way to make the websocket behave in a non-blocking way so that other responses/ping can be handled?

Comment: It sounds like your ping interval is way too short.  How big a messages are you sending and how long does it take them to be sent and received?  It's TCP so data is sent serially.  A ping won't actually be sent over the wire until the large data in front of it is sent and acknowledged.  If that takes a long time, then you need to slow down and not try to send a ping right away when the prior large data is still being sent.

Comment: It is currently 90 secs. But that shouldn't matter, since even if I increase it, I can't control what will be download speed of a client for ,let's say, an image. The image size can't be controlled too.

Comment: Then, it may be a problem with your webSocket library.  It needs to not try to send the ping until some significant time after the previous message has been sent.  What else do you expect us to say.  It shouldn't be sending a ping right after a message was just sent.  The ping should be going out ONLY after some period of time of inactivity after prior data was sent and that time needs to be long enough that any latent or slow client will be able to respond.  That's how a ping/pong system needs to work in order to be effective and not have false positives.

Comment: How big an image are you sending?  I would argue that you should send an URL to the client and let the browser request an image with HTTP using that URL and get the image bits off your websocket and make this whole problem go away.  A webSocket is not really designed to be a download system.  While one can use it for lots of things, it has strengths and not-so-strengths.  It's a lot better with smaller payloads that don't interfere with other uses of the same channel and don't cause problems with pings.

Comment: Image download via http is a valid solution.
The client can be using a 2G mobile connection which is unreliable and there may be responses which can span few kilobytes of json. If the connection breaks physically the client will not receive responses of other requests as well which will retried again.

Comment: OK, made my comment into an answer.

Comment: With [fragmented messages](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.4), you can send a ping frame while the message is still sending. But I am not sure, if your libraries support this.

Comment: @gre_gor - But, there should be no reason to send a ping frame when large amounts of data are being sent.  ping/pong frames are to detect when idle connections stop working.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to make the websocket behave in a non-blocking way so
>   that other responses/ping can be handled?

Not really.  A webSocket is a TCP socket underneath.  A TCP socket sends data serially.  If you're sending large amounts of data, all that data has to get delivered before the packet behind it can get delivered.  That's just how TCP works.  To work around this a browser uses multiple TCP connections when it wants to download multiple things at once or keep the download of one larger thing from interfering with its ability to do other things at the same time.

I would argue that a webSocket is not really the ideal transport for sending large image files over slow links - especially when you have pings and other data you want to have some responsiveness over the webSocket.

Probably a better scheme would be to just send an URL over the webSocket and have the client then request that image over a different HTTP request when it receives the URL.  Then, you use the webSocket only for smallish control messages and the large data transfer happens over parallel HTTP connections that don't interfere with the ability to continue to use the webSocket connection for other things (like pings or other control messages).

And, you know that HTTP, browsers and web servers are already highly optimized for serving images (since that's the majority of their bandwidth usage other than video).